# image scroll zoom as seen in youtube video

Tags: reactjs, react-native

is there some wrapper that makes me able to add this functionality ?

What i want is very similar to this : https://dev.to/reime005/image-scroll-zoom-in-react-native-29f7

but i can t understand how to refractor my code , as this article is based to an entire project with his logic

what would be very usefull is just to know how this feature is called, searching for "image scroll zoom" doesn't get me this precise functionality , there is a standard name for this functionality?

thanks to everyone in advance

i have tried to refractor my code as blog post but i can t recreate the functionality

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.